# Creating a program for batch snapping polylines and polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, c#, visual-studio

I currently work with large sums of lines data. I am editing them using different GIS software. I've realized that I can detect node problems in arcmap10.1.

I would like to know if it's possible to programmatically snap the detected dangling nodes and other issues. I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 (C#) installed with ArcObjects, but I am struggling with the code to develop such a stand-alone program.

This would make my work so much easier in the future as I have to manually snap these detected dangling nodes.

Comment: Why are you writing a program if you are looking for and correcting topological issues? You don't say what license level you have but if you have _ArcEditor_ license why not use the Topology rules to identify and correct your data? If you do not know what I am talking about then have a look at the help file.  Without more description sounds like you are re-inventing the wheel?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the `Integrate` ArcGIS tool instead if there are only slight imperfections in the data.

Comment: Be careful what tolerance you use, I've seen Integrate fix weeks worth of manual work and also completely destroy features. **keep a backup copy of your data before running integrate** and visually check your results are suitable before investing more time in the data.